# how to solve HADOOP_PREFIX replaced by HADOOP_HOME error?

Tags: linux, hadoop

I'm new to hadoop.Every time i run any command on hadoop i get a warning :

> WARNING: "HADOOP_PREFIX has been replaced by HADOOP_HOME. Using value of HADOOP_PREFIX.

How to get rid of this warning and why it appears. I'm using

```
export $HADOOP_PREFIX="my hadoop address"
```

What should i need to do ? I'm using Kali Linux. I also search for HADOOP_HOME in my hadoop directory using grep command and then replace them with HADOOP_PREFIX.

Comment: HADOOP_HOME is inferred variable based on where command is invoked from. But you also can set it up in your profile files. https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop HADOOP_PREFIX is depreciated and you want to remove it form your environment settings

Comment: How can i remove it from my environment setting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just solved my problem by simply follow the instruction: http://dbversity.com/warning-hadoop_home-is-deprecated/

and replace the command unset HADOOP_HOME to unset HADOOP_PREFIX
or simply edit ~/.bashrc and replace HADOOP_PREFIX to HADOOP_HOME.